# Updating Facebook like URL in jQuery

Tags: jquery, facebook

I have the following script.  As you can see it does update the fb href but for some strange reason the like fails to process.  Have I messed something?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        $('fb\\:like').attr('href', $("#URL").val());
    });
});
</script>
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=174802005910704&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:like href="#" send="false" layout="box_count" width="80" show_faces="false" font=""></fb:like>
<input type="text" id="URL" />
<input type="button" id="submit" value="go">
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I see what you are trying to do.. You are trying to get a user to like another page, by clicking like on one page. Not going to work bro, the fb:like button is rendered in an iframe and you can't change its href programmaticaly after its rendered. Nice try though :)

Answer (score 0):

No this will not do much because the `<fb:like>` tag has already been processed and rendered. all you are doing (if it actually works) is changing the attribute, which has no effect whatsoever

Try to explain what you are trying to accomplish and you will get a better answer

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm trying to update the Facebook like URL from a form..   


<input type="text" id="URL" />
<input type="button" id="submit" value="go">

Comment: You are successfuly updating it, but that wont change anything on your page, try to take a look at your DOM using firebug, than you will understand better my answer, the like button is turned in to an iframe and doesn't depend on the like tag anymore

Comment: How do you change the attribute before render?

Comment: you change it in the html or you dynamicaly insert it, with the correct url attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your html

```
<div class="share"></div>
```

On load and when a button is pressed or some state is changed call this function

```
function update_share_location() {

    // Empty previous share stuff
    $('.share').empty();

    // Your new share location
    var url_loc = 'http://yournewshare.com';

    share_options = '<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href='+url_loc+'&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=250&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=26" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:200px; height:26px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';

    // Update html
    $('.share').html(share_options);


}
```